# Allure stopped working I'm getting Connection Refused in Chrome

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, jestjs, puppeteer, allure

I created a series of simple tests and run them using "npm test". The tests run and then:

> Users/MYNAME@login_tests % npm run report
>
> > generated-test@1.0.0 report /Users/MYNAME/puppetryTests/export
>
> > allure serve
>
> Generating report to temp directory...
>
> Report successfully generated to /var/folders/nj/h39x0fk54qg85l5kq_vxmx400000gp/T/5115131715937267387/allure-report
>
> Starting web server...
>
> 2020-01-02 12:20:58.440:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1580ms to
>
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
>
> Server started at http://10.5.28.57:52639/.

But when I go to the site all I get is a connection refused notice. Chrome & Firefox & Safari. The weird thing is that this morning it all worked nicely. I saw the pretty html page. I started simple server with python in the same directory and viewed the results at localhost:8000 but it's missing all of allure's prettiness.

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled npm and even xcode many times to try to get to the root of this problem. I was unable to get figure out what went wrong, but eventually I was able to get it to work. I ran >$ npm run report like normal and it opened a browser window I couldn't connect to, but for some reason >$ allure serve -h 127.0.0.1 made a page I can get to. Could not tell you why. I tried the solution of adding this argument to chromium --allow-file-access-from-files but that did not help.

Answer (score 5):

The IP address that Allure serves in might be the issue. I had the same issue and got it resolved by choosing the localhost as the IP.

```
allure serve -h localhost
```

Comment: was it the 'pretty' version or the stripped down one?